# Confusion with Substring and Parse in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, substring

I am trying to parse a 14 character `varchar` (not always 14 characters, sometimes 12 or 10 or 0) column so that it displays the results in two parts by preceding a decimal on the second result.

```
EmployeeCode        ResultCol1      ResultCol2
-----------------------------------------------
42135430620000      421354306200    .00
42135431750000      421354317500    .01
42135431740001      421354317400    .00
42135430923333      421354309233    .33
42135432370000      421354323700    .00
431354324200        4313543242      .00
42135432320000      421354323200    .00
42135432390000      421354323900    .00
42135430940000      421354309400    .00
421354324300        4213543243      .00
42135431980000      421354319800    .00
421354324400        4213543244      .00
42135432830000      421354328300    .00
421354323800        4213543238      .00
421354328500        4213543285      .00
421354328100        4213543281      .00
421354328400        4213543284      .00
421354328200        4213543282      .00
421354328600        4213543286      .00
421354330000        4213543300      .00
```

Comment: Are the second and third rows in your example correct?

Comment: Hi Simon, the second and the third rows are how the results should be. Sorry, for not elaborating that earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` string functions.

```
SELECT EmployeeCode,
       LEFT(EmployeeCode, CASE
                             WHEN Len(EmployeeCode) = 0 THEN 1
                             ELSE Len(EmployeeCode) - 2
                           END)      AS ResultCol1,
       '.' + RIGHT(EmployeeCode, 2) AS ResultCol2 
FROM   yourtable
```

**DEMO**

```
DECLARE @EmployeeCode VARCHAR(50)='42135430620000'

SELECT @EmployeeCode as EmployeeCode,
       LEFT(@EmployeeCode, CASE
                             WHEN Len(@EmployeeCode) = 0 THEN 1
                             ELSE Len(@EmployeeCode) - 2
                           END)      AS ResultCol1,
       '.' + RIGHT(@EmployeeCode, 2) AS ResultCol2
```

**Result**

```
EmployeeCode    ResultCol1    ResultCol2
--------------  ------------  ----------
42135430620000  421354306200    .00
```